# document.ready jquery difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

In the master page I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the Index.cshtml I have the following code:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        ...</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a id="btnShowCustomers" data-role="button" href="#secondDiv"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        ...</div>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#btnShowCustomers').bind('click', function (event) {
            GetCustomers();
        });
    });

    function GetCustomers() {
        var webMethod = "Home/GetCustomers";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: webMethod,
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dataObj) {
                alert('lala');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Debugging with Firebug i get the following error:

document.ready is not a function
[Break On This Error] (document).ready(function (event) {

How is that possible? On document ready i want to register the handler for the button's click event.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace it to `$(document).ready(…` — you forgot to put `$` variable there.

Comment: For jQuery inclusion, why do you use razor nuget ? As it's an external resource, you should replace `<script src="@Url.Content("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` by `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: you can also use `$(function() {` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(document).ready(function (event) {
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be `$(document).ready(function (event) ...`

Notice the dollar sign prefixed to the start of the string - although this *can* differ, jQuery code generally uses this prefix to access its context for selectors and whatnot.

See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for some information on utilising jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you ar missing a $

```
 $(document).ready(function (event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(document).ready(function (event) {
```

You don't have `$` or `jQuery` before `(document)`, this it thinks it is calling `ready` directly on the `document` object. `ready` is a jQuery short cut, not a DOM method.

Answer (score 0):

if you include `JQuery` like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a shortcut you can also write

```
$(function(){
  //your code
});
```

which is equivalent to writing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //your code
});
```